# Is $\frac{a^x-1}{x}$ increasing in $x$ when $a>1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $f(x) = \frac{a^x-1}{x}$ increasing in $x \in (0,1)$ when $a>1$? Decreasing?

$$f'(x) = \frac{a^x (x \ln a - 1) + 1}{x^2}$$.

It is not clear to see whether $f' > 0$, $f' < 0$.

Comment: You could use the mean value theorem for this. We know that $a^x$ is monotone for $a>1$.

Comment: Let $x>y$. Then $\frac{a^y-1}{y} - \frac{a^x -1}{x} = f'(c)(y-x)$.  This still seems to depend on the sign of $f'$. What am I missing?

Comment: You can see $a^x>1$ when $a>1$, so $f'(x)>0$ when $x\ln(a)>0$, so it's true.

Comment: try $a=e...........$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it is not so difficult. Let $\ln(a)=k$ then $e^k=a$ and we are after $$\frac{e^{xk}(xk-1)+1}{x^2}$$ is positive or negative for all $x\in(0,1)$. According to this subtitution we have also $a>1$, $k>0$ and $e^k>1$. The denominator has no role in this calculation therefore we have $$f(xk)=e^{xk}(xk-1)+1$$ which is equilvalent to $f(y)=e^{y}(y-1)+1$ with $y=xk$. We can write it as $e^{y}y-e^{y}+1>^?0$ which is $e^{y}y>^?(e^{y}-1)$ which is $y>^?(e^{y}-1)/e^{y}$ which is $y>^?1-e^{-y}$ which is $y+e^{-y}>^?1$. Note that the inequality holds if the minimum of $y+e^{-y}$ on $(0,1)$ is greater than $1$. The value of $y$ which minimizes $y+e^{-y}$ on $(0,1)$ is some $y=\epsilon>0$ which is infinitesimally small. It is then obvious that $y+e^{-y}>1$ is true becase for $y=0$ we have $y+e^{-y}\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem generalizes to any sufficiently smooth function $f(x)$ which is defined at $0$ and concave up on  a subinterval of the positive reals (with left endpoint $0$). Define 
$$h(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x},$$
and find $h'(x)$ by the usual rule, which in this case may be rearranged to
$$h'(x)=\frac{1}{x}[f'(x)-h(x)].\tag{1}$$
Now from the mean value theorem, $h(x)=f'(c)$ for some $c \in (0,x),$ and since concavity of $f$ means $f'$ is increasing, we have from $c<x$ that $h(x)=f'(c)<f'(x),$ so that (since $x>0$) the right side of $(1)$ is positive, i.e. $h'(x)>0.$

For the problem here, $f(x)=a^x$ has the required concave up property, and $h(x)=(a^x-1)/x.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x<y$. Then for some $c \in (x,y) \subset (0,1)$, $\frac{a^y-1}{y} - \frac{a^x -1}{x} = f'(c)(y-x)$.

Therefore the sign of $f'(c)$ will determine whether $f$ is increasing.  But $f'(c)=a^c(c\ln a - 1) + 1 > 0$ iff $a^c (1-\ln {a^c}) < 1$ iff $1-\ln {a^c} < \frac{1}{a^c}$ which is true since $\ln{a^c} > \ln 1 = 0$.

Is this a fast way to do it?